# JavaScript Module issue?

Tags: javascript

```
    Module = (function () {


    var Method  = function () {

        this.doSomething =function () {
            return "doSomething";
        };

    }


    return {
        Method:Method
    };

})();
var value=Module.Method.doSomething;
console.log(value);
```

New to Javascript, coming from a java background.

Why is value coming back as undefined?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have an object of `Method` to access the property `doSomething`, you can achieve it like

```js
 Module = (function () {


    var Method  = function () {

        this.doSomething =function () {
            return "doSomething";
        };

    }


    return {
        Method:Method
    };

})();
var value= new Module.Method();
alert(value.doSomething());
```

you can also approach it like

```
Module = (function () {

  var Method  = function () {

    this.doSomething =function () {
        return "doSomething";
    };

  }
  return {
    Method:new Method
 };

})();
var value=Module.Method.doSomething();
alert(value);
```

Comment: var value = (new Module).Method();

Comment: @OctoD : this wont work as we dont want the obejct of module to be created. instead we need the object of Method. Thats why i put so.

Comment: Whops, my mistake, sorry. I should stop drinking early in the morning :)

Comment: @OctoD : no problem brother. you dont have to stop drinking for this reason. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
 var value= new Module.Method().doSomething();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yy29c20v/)

Answer (score 0):

`Module.Method` is a function, apparently designed to be used as a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). You're also not calling the function.

```
var value=new Module.Method().doSomething();
                          ^^^ create an instance of Module.Method
                            ^^^ call the doSomething method of it.
```